# ¿Qué hace internamente el return de un método con las llamadas a filter y map?

Tags: python

Necesito que alguien me explique qué hace el `return` del método `busca_inmueble(inmuebles, presupuesto)` de este código que vi en una web de ejercicios:

```
inmuebles = [{'año': 2000, 'metros': 100, 'habitaciones': 3, 'garaje': True,'zona': 'A'},
{'año': 2012, 'metros': 60, 'habitaciones': 2, 'garaje': True, 'zona': 'B'},
{'año': 1980, 'metros': 120, 'habitaciones': 4, 'garaje': False, 'zona': 'A'},
{'año': 2005, 'metros': 75, 'habitaciones': 3, 'garaje': True, 'zona': 'B'},
{'año': 2015, 'metros': 90, 'habitaciones': 2, 'garaje': False, 'zona': 'A'}]

def add_precio(inmueble):
    precio = (inmueble["metros"]*1000+inmueble["habitaciones"]*5000+int(inmueble["garaje"])*15000)*(1-(2020- inmueble["año"])/100)
    if inmueble["zona"]=="B":
        precio*= 1.5
    inmueble["precio"] = precio
    return inmueble
def busca_inmueble(inmuebles, presupuesto):
    def filtro(inmueble):
        return inmueble['precio'] <= presupuesto
    
    return list(filter(filtro,map(add_precio, inmuebles)))
print(busca_inmueble(inmuebles, 100000))
```

la conclusión y lo que hace lo tengo claro, lo que no entiendo es qué hace internamente el `return` del método con las llamadas `filter` y `map`.

Comment: añade el precio y luego filtra. Fíjate que `return inmueble['precio'] <= presupuesto` devuelve un booleano (cierto/falso), por lo que devolverá solamente los elementos que cumplan la condición.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supongo que te refieres a la línea:

```
return list(filter(filtro,map(add_precio, inmuebles)))
```

Esta línea utiliza un modelo de programación *funcional* en el que se evita el tener que escribir muchos bucles explícitos porque estás usando funciones que usan internamente esos bucles, ayudadas por otras funciones adicionales que le pasas como parámetro.

En concreto, la función `map()` espera dos parámetros. El primero sería una función  (en tu caso `add_precio`) y el segundo un iterable (en concreto `inmuebles`). Lo que hace `map()` es iterar por el iterable y para cada uno de sus elementos le aplica la función, y va devolviendo uno a uno los resultados. Así que en tu caso se va ejecutando `add_precio()` sobre cada uno de los elementos de `inmuebles` y se van retornando los resultados de esas ejecuciones, de uno en uno.

Esos resultados son tomados por la función `filter()` que espera también dos parámetros. El primero ha de ser una función de la que se espera que retorne `True` o `False` (en tu caso sería la función `filtro`) y el segundo ha de ser un iterable (en nuestro caso, la secuencia de valores retornados por `map()`. Lo que hace `filter()` es invocar la función `filtro()` sobre cada uno de los valores que le vienen del iterable, y si el resultado es `True`, lo deja pasar y si es `False` no. Al final por tanto `filter()` devuelve otro iterable que contiene solo los elementos  para los que `filtro()` devolvió `True`.

Ese iterable se pasa finalmente a `list()` para que lo convierta en una lista.

Por tanto podemos ver que el flujo de la información sería:

```
inmuebles --> add_precio --> filtro --> list
```

Cada elemento de inmuebles se "transforma" en otra cosa por la función `add_precio()` y el resultado se filtra y pasa (o no) a `list()`.

### Otra forma de hacer lo mismo

Todo lo que se pueda hacer con programación funcional se puede hacer también con comprensiones de listas. En opinión de Guido Van Rossum (creador de Python) las comprensiones son mucho más legibles y preferibles sobre la modalidad funcional.

La versión con comprensiones sería así:

```
return [add_precio(inmueble) for inmueble in inmuebles if filtro(add_precio(inmueble)) ]
```

La expresión anterior tiene no obstante un problema, y es que se está llamando dos veces a `add_precio()`, una para pasar el resultado al filtro para ver si "pasa o no pasa", y la otra para añadirlo a la lista resultante. Esto es ineficiente.

Podemos evitar las dos llamadas si hacemos otra comprensión interna:

```
return [ x for x in (add_precio(inmueble) for inmueble in inmuebles) if filtro(x) ]
```

Aquí se crea primero un iterable interno con los resultados de `add_precio()` y luego se itera por él para ver qué valores (x) pasan el filtro. Aunque esta segunda forma es más eficiente, es también más ilegible.

A partir de Python 3.8 se tiene el operador "morsa" (`:=`) que permite evaluar algo a la vez que se asigna, lo que nos permite una tercera forma de escribir la comprensión:

```
return [ x for inmueble in inmuebles if filtro(x:=add_precio(inmueble))]
```

Aquí no hay comprensión interna anidada, sino que se va iterando por cada `inmueble` en `inmuebles` y para cada uno se evalua si pasa el filtro, pero en la propia llamada al filtro capturamos en `x` (gracias al `:=`) el resultado de `add_precio()` que así sólo se ejecuta una vez. Si el filtro retorna `True`, añadimos `x` a la lista (porque la comprensión comienza con `[x for ...`)